# Is there a service for changing all my profile pictures at the same time?

Tags: webapp-rec, profile-picture

I have three main profile pictures: Facebook, Google and Gravatar. Is there any way to update all of them at the same time?

Comment: Use an OpenID or Facebook Connect to log in ;-)

Comment: Is there a way to do the same thing with facebook and twitter?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In your Google profile, you can use a URL to define your profile image. You can do the same in your Gravatar profile. The only place where you can't do that is on Facebook.

Your Facebook profile picture has a permanent URL, `http://graph.facebook.com/numericUserID/picture`. You can then use that as your profile image for both Google and Gravatar. That way, the next time you change your Facebook profile picture, the change will be propagated to other two services.

Additionally, you can get a bigger image by adding a `type=large` argument to the URL: `http://graph.facebook.com/numericUserID/picture?type=large`

Comment: Nice way of thinking outside "the box."

Comment: Gravatar made the image REALLY pixelly, but otherwise, this worked great.

Comment: [Social framework returns “(#803) Cannot query users by their username (username)” when trying to get user feed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23615961/5033247)

Answer (score 5):

Was that not the purpose of [Gravatar](http://en.gravatar.com/)? e.g. change all your pic references to point to your Gravatar (*Globally* Recognized **Avatar**) then just update your Gravatar when you want to change it.

(Note: changes may not take right away (on any service) depending on how the caching is done)

Comment: The thing is that many big sites like Google and Facebook don't use Gravatar.

Comment: And I hope they don't. As far as I can tell, Gravatar's business model is as a web usage tracking service. Even if I'm mistaken about that, a single point of aggregation or failure is a Bad Thing.