# Is it possible to link my Gravatar to my Gmail/Google account?

Tags: gmail, google, avatar, gravatar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a service for changing all my profile pictures at the same time?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1157/is-there-a-service-for-changing-all-my-profile-pictures-at-the-same-time)

I want to be able to update my profile picture on all of my accounts simultaneously. The one thing that's not linked to my Gravatar is my Gmail/Google account. Is it possible to link my Gravatar to my Gmail/Google account?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/1157/85

Answer (score 0):

see this it's a greasemonkey scriptt by jon!
http://www.jonefox.com/blog/2010/01/25/gravatar-in-gmail-update/ and try this chrome extension http://gravatar.wordpress.com/2011/02/17/chrome-extension-for-gmail/

Comment: I think the idea is not to use Gravatar images in gmail, but to make Google Profile get the profile image from Gravatar.